# Switching between two already started activities without closing any one of them in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to switch between two already started activities in android. I want switch between them like I want to put one in background and second in front and then on an event vice versa. Is it possible if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement use Fragments instead of creating different Activities, for this you have to extend your class by [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) instead of Activity.

Find below link for example on Fragment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example

Comment: oops... thats gona take long time...i got it.