# Split screen in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, split

I want to split screen like [ipad](http://appshopper.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/tumblr_kzrjkt6sQr1qz4rgr.png).I dont know exactly name.Can anybody know how can i do that or example?

Comment: This is rather a search in google, not a constructive question.

Comment: Use Fragments 

see below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812035/switching-between-two-already-started-activities-without-closing-any-one-of-them/12812997#12812997

Comment: I find that.http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-sdk-tools-revision-20-now.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Fragment for that . A fragment is a class implementing a portion of an activity

Check this tutorial for that.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use android [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to do with this same.

And also refer [This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) for example of Fragment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find that.We can chose masterdetail screen .İt is easier i think[android masterdetail screen option](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-sdk-tools-revision-20-now.html)